# Is it possible to define pgf keys that accept values with an xparse-like syntax?

Tags: pgfkeys, xparse

The `pgfkeys` package has the  `/.code` handler that allows one to define the code to be executed when the user sets a key, as if it executed a macro with `#1` as the value. The `/.code args` handler allows to provide an actual argument list in `\def`-style so one can define fancy keys, like `rectangle/.code args={#1 by #2}{...}` that can be set as `rectangle=13 by 12`.

My question is: is there some package that integrates `xparse` with `pgfkeys` in order to use `xparse`-like syntax (e.g. `{m o m}`) to define the arguments of the key?

Example:

```
\pgfkeys{my key/.xparse code={o m}{\def\mykey{Required: #2, Optional: #1}}}
\pgfkeys{my key = [Hello]{John}} % prints 'Required: John, Optional: Hello'
```

Comment: I've tried a few things but since PGFkeys uses delimited arguments and `o m` isn't, calling `my key = John` might lead to only `J` picked up as `#2`. But defining the `DocumentCommand` delimited lead to other weird things that won't be consistent with `xparse` when something like `omo` is used as an argment definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides just defining your own DocumentCommand and just forwarding everything from PGFkeys there manually, say

```
\NewDocumentCommand\myKey{o m}{<stuff>}
\pgfkeys{my key/.code=\myKey#1}
```

we could do it with a handler that does the same.

```
my key/.xparse code = {o m}{<stuff>}
```

which can be used with

```
my key = [opt]{mand}
```

and it'll work right:

```
\myKey[opt]{mand}
```

However, when used without an optional argument, e.g.

```
my key = mand
% or
my key = {mand}
```

PGFkeys will lose some braces and the call to `\myKey` will be

```
\myKey mand
```

which will only grab `m` as `#2` and leave `and` around.

We'd need `my key = {{{{mand}}}}`.

---

PGFkeys works in one aspect very different than `\newcommand`s or `\NewDocumentCommand`s: Every key-macro is a delimited macro whose arguments and with `\pgfeov`. Internally, all key-macros get this appended.

Unfortunately, `xparse` doesn't provide the same interface, it only knows

- `t` → an optional token (which will toggle a Boolean) and
- `u` → a mandatory argument *u*ntil the specified tokens are encountered.

I've chose the latter. That means, every

```
key/.xparse code={<args>}{<code>}
```

will actually be defined with the arguments `<args> u\pgfeov`.

This makes it very easy to use `xparse` for PGFkeys with one caveat: There's always a mandatory last argument the user **does not** specify.

This isn't great but I would reiterate a recommendation from the `xparse`: Keep It Simple (paraphrasing).
Just don't put any fancy arguments at the end.

In your case, you would just use `o` since, again, a mandatory argument at the end is mandatory.

```
\pgfkeys{my key/.xparse code={o}{Required: #2, Optional: #1}}
```

---

A few notes:

- If you need `.append xparse code` and similars a bit more work is necessary, I have a few ideas, though.
- I'm explicitly showing almost only bad cases in my code below don't be discouraged.
- I'm using `\DeclareDocumentCommand` since this will just overwrite the macro (as PGFkeys does with `.code`) even though the `xparse` manual advices against it:

  > This should be used sparingly.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys,xparse,tabularx}
\pgfqkeys{/handlers}{
  .xparse code/.code 2 args={%
    \expandafter\DeclareDocumentCommand
      \csname pgfk@\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@cmd\endcsname
      {#1u\pgfeov}{#2}%
    % probably useless unless .xparse append code is needed
    %\pgfkeyssetvalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@args}{#1u\pgfeov}%
    %\pgfkeyssetvalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@body}{#2}%
  },
  .xparse style/.code 2 args=%
    \pgfkeysalso{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.xparse code={#1}{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}},
}
\newcommand*\doKey[2]{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}} & \pgfkeys{#1}
  \ifx\\#2\\\else\par\def\tt##1 {\texttt{##1} }\sffamily$\to$ #2\fi\\}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{my key1/.xparse code   = { o }{Required1: #2, Optional1: #1}}
\pgfkeys{my key2/.xparse code   = { o }{Required2: #2, Optional2: #1}}
\pgfkeys{my style/.xparse style = { o o }%
                {my key1 = [1]{#1}, /utils/exec=\par, my key2 = {#2}}}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l X}
  \doKey{my key1  = [Hello]{John}}{}
  \doKey{my key2  = John2        }{}
  \doKey{my style = [Foo]Bar     }{\tt Bar is lost (and no error message)}
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{1ex}% without the #4
\pgfkeys{omo/.xparse code={omo}{Opt1: #1, Req2: #2, Opt2: #3}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l X}
  \doKey{omo = [opt1]{Foo}[opt3]}{}
  \doKey{omo = [opt1]{FooBar}   }{}
  \doKey{omo = {FooBar}         }{\tt ooBar is lost}
  \doKey{omo = {Foo}Bar         }{\tt Bar is lost}
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{1ex}% as above but with #4 after the #2
\pgfkeys{omo/.xparse code={O{--}mO{--}}{Opt1: #1, Req2: #2#4, Opt2: #3}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l X}
  \doKey{omo = [opt1]{Foo}[opt3]}{}
  \doKey{omo = [opt1]{FooBar}   }{}
  \doKey{omo = {FooBar}         }{ooBar is lost}
  \doKey{omo = {Foo}Bar         }{Bar is caught}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! Thanks!